# Dom4j selectNodes with filter in XPATH

Tags: java, xpath, dom4j

```
<Results>   
  <Details>  
    <Number> 01 </Number>
    <Seq> 01 </Seq>
  <Details>  
 <Details>  
    <Number> 02 </Number>
    <Seq> 01 </Seq>
  <Details>  
 <Details>  
    <Number> 01 </Number>
    <Seq> 03 </Seq>
  <Details>  
</Results>
```

I do :

```
 .selectNodes("//Results/Details/Number = '1'");
```

to select all Number nodes = 1, but it returns "**true**" ! instead of list of nodes.
How to get all nodes Number = 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression `"//Results/Details/Number = '1'"` selects all `//Results/Details/Number` and then returns if one of these nodes - when converted to a string - equals `'1'`.
(And given your XML document this should return `false` not `true`).

To select all `Number` nodes whose text content equals `1` use the expression:

```
//Results/Details/Number[. = 1]
```

Comment: Great!. it works, thank you. Yes, my example should returns false. Have a great day